# Service returns DTO object; how to modify the class type so it appears to be a non-DTO object to end user?

Tags: c#, web-services

Running into a bit of a snag on this and wondering where I am going awry.

Our server has two classes: Order and OrderDto. The Order class creates our domain objects and the OrderDto class creates our DTO objects.

The DTO class has the following attributes modifying it:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Order"), SoapType("Order")]
public class OrderDto : IDto
```

The intention of the XmlRoot/SoapType attribute is to make OrderDto appear as the class Order to an end user. It is currently not doing so. Here's my web service's method and it being called from another project via service reference:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Creates a new order with project information.")]
public OrderDto CreateOrderByProject(string name, string description)
{
    OrderDto orderDto = OrderDto.Create(name, description);
    return orderDto;
}

[Test]
public void CreateOrderWithValidProjectSubcode()
{
    OrderDto orderDto = WorkflowServices.CreateOrderByProject(OrderName, OrderDescription);
}
```

As you can see, WorkflowServices.CreateOrderByProject declares itself to be returning an object of type OrderDto and not of type Order.

How can this code be modified such that end users see Order and not OrderDto?

EDIT: It appears that using XmlType(TypeName = "Order") may be sufficient. Going to continue to play around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to tag the class with XmlType(TypeName = "Order") instead of XmlRoot("Order")

Answer (score 0):

Use two different namespaces for your domain objects and your DTO objects. That way you can use the same name for the objects (ex: your domain and DTO object are both named "Order").  In the layer that you translate between your domain and DTO objects you use the namespace to distinguish them (ex: domain.Order and Dto.Order). Only expose the namespace for the DTO objects in your web service API.